# bash script : end of line character issue : file from excel

Tags: excel, bash, newline

Working in bash under Linux ubuntu 10 here

I have Bash script that reads lines from gedit-created .txt file and pushes then into an array. Works as expected.

However when my input is a .txt generated from Excel it throws the error

```
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "

echo -n $elem | od -x yields
0000000 3533 0d32
0000004
```

I can't help feeling I'm *almost* at the solution, but it is eluding me, much to my frustration. I'd appreciate some help

Thanks

@MarcB
file from excel: (cut'n'pasted from gedit; contrary to appearance there are no blank lines in this file; rather lines alternate int, str, int, str ...)
0

A?GATCGGAAGAGCGTCGTGTAGGGAAAGAGTGTAGATC
1

A?GATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACATCACGAT[AC]T

2

A?GATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACCGATGTAT[AC]T

3

A?GATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACTTAGGCAT[AC]T

4

A?GATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACTGACCAAT[AC]T

5

A?GATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACACAGTGAT[AC]T

6

A?GATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACGCCAATAT[AC]T

7

A?GATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACCAGATCAT[AC]T

8

A?GATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACACTTGAAT[AC]T

9

A?GATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACGATCAGAT[AC]T

10

A?GATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCACTAGCTTAT[AC]T

```
rtstxt='readthrusequences.txt'

# establish readthrusequence array ---------------------------------------------
# push into sparse array the readthru adapter sequence for each TruSeq index
# use the TruSeq Index number as key to the sequence
forts=${pathsir}${rtstxt}  # FileOf ReadThruSequences
  rts=( $(cat ${forts}) )

idx=""
elem=""
isIdx=1
for elem in ${rts[@]}; do
  echo '$elem:'${elem}
# echo 'elem:' ${elem} 'before IF - isIdx:' $isIdx '- idx:' $idx
  if [[ $isIdx = 1 ]]; then 
    echo ' 1_block - $isIdx:'$isIdx' - elem:'$elem' - idx:'$idx; 
    indexseq[$elem]=0; 
    #echo "  indexseq[elem] set to ${indexseq[$elem]}"; 
    idx=$elem; 
    #echo "  idx set to elem (i.e. $idx)"; 
    isIdx=0; 
    #echo "  isIdx reset to $isIdx"; 
    #echo " " ; 
  else 
    #echo " 2_block - isIdx:$isIdx - elem:$elem - idx:$idx"; 
    indexseq[$idx]=$elem; 
    #echo "  indexseq[idx] set to ${indexseq[$idx]}"; 
    isIdx="1"; idx="0"; 
    #echo "  isIdx reset to $isIdx - idx reset to $idx";
    #echo ""; 
  fi
#  echo "keys (TruSeq index): ${!indexseq[*]}"
#  echo "vals (indexed adapter seq): ${indexseq[*]}"
done
```

This code pushes the file contents into an array, using the int as indices and the str and values.

The commented lines were debugs. If the first is un-commented the console yields

```
before IF - isIdx: 1 - idx:
 - idx:k - $isIdx:1 - elem:0
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
```

pointing definitely to a line end issue; but I've banged my head on this wall for too long & haven't found a solution. I know there's a simple one ...

Comment: Can you how the relevant bits of the bash script, and the actual text of this excel-generated file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An excel generated file almost certainly uses the \r\n character pair to terminate each line. (There may be a Ctrl-Z char at the end of the file). Unix based systems expect only the \n character  to terminate a line of input (and Ctrl-D (not usually) as end-of-file marker).

Solution, either edit file to remove ^M chars (\r) at the end of each line (also check for ^Z at end of file and remove that too), OR the standard is

```
 dos2unix file file2 .... filen
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: @shelter ... yup, that did indeed help; perfect answer, complete with explanation and solution. Thank you!